# Short story where life is lived out of chronological order

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I think I read this short story (within the past five years) which was a science fiction (possibly post-apocalyptic) short story anthology.

There was some kind of event which caused the world to become untethered to chronology so that everyone lived their lives in a non-linear fashion. The main character experiences days when he is with his wife and happy and then days where she's left him for someone else. At the end it's the day before he dies but he talks to his friend knowing he'll see him again (I think at some place which serves bad coffee).

Comment: Probably not the one you have in mind, but ["If This Is Winnetka, You Must Be Judy"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61861) by [F. M. Busby](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?339) is a classic take on the life-lived-out-of-order theme. In several collections, but apparently none in the last 30 years, or with a post-apocalyptic theme. I can't recall if everyone is living their lives out of order or just the main character(s), and my copy is inaccessible at the moment. Like I said, probably not it, but good.

Comment: Alternatively, there's [The Time Traveller's Wife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Traveler%27s_Wife) which also deals with a relationship conducted out-of-order.

Comment: Might also be Kurt Vonnegut's [*Timequake,*](http://www.amazon.com/Timequake-Kurt-Vonnegut/dp/0425164349) which has everyone in the world reliving, action by action, the last ten years.

Comment: @user14111 Will check it out but pretty sure this story is more recent.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks - read and loved it, but this is definitely a short story.

Comment: @JoeL. Thanks, but this is definitely a short story, and a less-well-known author.

Comment: I'd say "If This is Winnetka, You Must Be Judy" is it.

Comment: @Covertwalrus Good story, but only the main character is living life non-chronologically. In the one I read everyone was.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't match up exactly, but it sounds a lot like Kurt Vonnegut's *Slaughterhouse-Five*. The main character, Billy Pilgrim, becomes "unstuck" in time, and meets aliens who experience time in a non-linear fashion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughterhouse-Five

Comment: Thanks, but I've read Slaughterhouse Five and this was definitely a short story.